# How to deactivate Angular theming without uninstalling Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes, theming

I've been getting this in the console, and I feel like the application has been also somewhat slow...

How do I get rid of this?[image: console warning]

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material is all about styling the UI, if you don't want the basic theme, just create your own => https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#the-core-mixin

If you are looking for just the UI Behavior components, then you already go it in angular cdk: https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories and so you should get rid of angular material.

For instance, you can find drag&drop behavior feature in =>

```
import {CdkDragDrop} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
```